# Close number not showing

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, close-reasons, vote-to-close, information-display

I've voted to close [this question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/26793/which-nosql-databases-every-programmer-should-know-about), but it shows no close vote, but when I vote to close again it says I've already voted.  See pics.

[image: No close number]

[image: Already closed]

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to assume this had to do with the ongoing transition out of Beta, since I've now lost my privileges to close.

Comment: yep that would be why.